# How to move C++ queue's front item into the back?

Tags: c++, stl, queue

Suppose I have the following queue:

```
queue <int> throws;
```

and an integer variable ii [which is incremented by 1 until my queue is empty]..

Now I want to do,
For every odd count of ii, I want to move the front item into the back.
And for every even count ii, current front item will pop.

Suppose my queue have the following item: 2 4 7 11 13 95

```
ii = 1 >> 4 7 11 13 95 2  
ii = 2 >> 7 11 13 95 2  
ii = 3 >> 11 13 95 2 7
```

I have tried `throws.back() = throws.front();`
but it may be remove the current back item.
In this manner. Can anyone tell me how can I do that?

- Thanks

Comment: [According to the queue documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue), push is right up your alley.

Answer (score 2):

To access the first element, use

```
int i = throws.first();
```

To remove the first element, use

```
throws.pop();
```

To move the first element to the end of the queue:

```
throws.push(throws.first());
throws.pop();
```

Comment: @DavidSchwartz yes, but a touch excessive for an `int`, I think.

Comment: I am not sure this is what the author asked for. You COPY it to the back. The author asked for MOVE. (Thats why i am here, I am not sure about the MOVE solution)

Answer (score 0):

This will solve your problem:

```
do {
    if(ii % 2 == 1) {
        throws.push(throws.first());
    }
    throws.pop();
    i++;
} while(!throws.empty());
```

Comment: Recommend explaining what that code does and why it is a good solution. Code only answers help only the cargo cults.

Answer (score 0):

```
 throws.push(throws.front());
 throws.pop();
```